# Действия по завершении анимации

Tags: html, jquery

Здесь следует обратить внимание на цвет абзаца, это работает так: когда блок скрыт - абзац красный, когда блок появляется - абзац чёрный. Абзац меняет цвет лишь после завершения функции `slideToggle()`. Но такая проблема: когда блок раскрыт, и при этом нажать на абзац 2 раза, то блок остаётся открытым, а у абзаца цвет красный, а не чёрный. Долго решал проблему уже крайний случай.

```js
$('p').click(function() {
  if ($('.q1').is(':hidden')) {
    $('.q1').stop().slideToggle(function() {
      $('p').css({
        background: 'black'
      });
    });
  } else {
    $('.q1').stop().slideToggle(function() {
      $('p').css({
        background: 'red'
      });
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.q1 {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100px;
  background: black;
  display: none;
}
p {
  float: right;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>123312
  <div class="q1"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очевидно ошибка в том, что вы используете 2 разных условия, которые определяют скрыт объект или нет.

`is(':hidden')` определяет скрыт ли объект полностью

`slideDown()` определяет скрыт ли объект или уже начал скрываться.

Но вместо того, чтобы пытаться предсказать, как поведет себя `slideDown()`, не легче ли сделать проверку после анимации, чтобы определить состояние уже дефакто?

Рабочий код:

```js
$('p').click(function() {

  $('.q1').stop(true).slideToggle(function() {

    if ($('.q1').is(':hidden')) {
      $('p').css({
        background: 'red'
      });
    } else {
      $('p').css({
        background: 'black'
      });
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.q1 {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100px;
  background: black;
  display: none;
}
p {
  float: right;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>123312
  <div class="q1"></div>
```

Comment: Ах вот оно что, спасибо большое! теперь понятно что видимость объекта определяется после завершении анимации.